# Trimming a part of string in sql needed for datatrieve

Tags: sql, trim

I have a column called notation in the correspondence table in our database. The values are as such for this column:

```
notation

SSQSUPER405575681 || 032-797 || 034828 1141289
SGQSUPER405575091 || 032-797 || 034828 1140802
SGQSUPER395729693 || 032-797 || 034828 1061943
```

I want to have this value only SSQSUPER405575681 or SGQSUPER405575091 for notation column and trim the rest part of the string such as || 032-797 || 034828 1141289 in the 1st row and || 032-797 || 034828 1140802 in 2nd row.

Please tell me how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Sybase functions are often pretty similar to T-SQL for SQL Server, so to extract the desired substrings out the *notation* column, try:

```
select 
    substring([notation], 1, patindex ('%||%',[notation]) - 1) as f1,
    substring([notation], 
        patindex ('%||%',[notation]),
        len([notation]) - patindex ('%||%',[notation]) ) as f2
from [correspondence]
```

If that doesn't work exactly, you might see if there is some variation in the way the Sybase functions work.